# Angular distinguish between multiple tree nodes

Tags: angular, angular5

I am developing a web application in Angular. I have a tree component in page. I have dynamic tabs and content as tree nodes. I am struggling to distinguish between the nodes. Below is the code of dynamic tab and tree.

Below is typescript code:

```
this.arrayTabs.forEach(eachObj => {
  this.tabs.push({
    title: eachObj,
    active: false,
    content: this.nodes
  });
})
```

Below is html code:

```
<tabset>
  <tab *ngFor="let tabz of tabs" [heading]="tabz.title">
    <div *ngIf="tabz.title==='Edit'">
      <tree-root #tree
        [nodes]="tabz.content"
        [options]="options">
        <ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node="node" let-index="index">
          <input type="checkbox" (change)="toggle($event.target,node)"
[checked]="node.data.checked">
          {{ node.data.name }}"
        </ng-template>
       </tree-root>
     </div>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

This tree looks like as below:

[image]

The problem I am facing as below. When I click on checkbox of infomodel under Add tab, same time checkbox in the Delete or other tabs will also be checked. Below is my checkbox checked event.

```
toggle(cb, node, tabtitle) {
  if (cb.checked) {
    node.data.checked = true;
  }
  else {
    node.data.checked = false;
  }
}
```

This is happening because when I do `node.data.checked=true` or `false` all the nodes are updating. Is there any way I can prevent this? Ideally nodes should be different for each tab. Is the method I am following correct or should I change my implementation?

Comment: could you create stackblitz  example it will be easy to help.

Comment: *Ideally nodes should be different for each tab* then do not put the exact same nodes in each tab as you're doing: `content: this.nodes`.

Comment: okay thanks. How can i create id for each node by default?

Comment: You don't need to create "id for each node by default?". You need to pass different nodes to each tab. Probably by creating recursive copies.

Comment: My nodes are same. So i am planning to have id field in each node so that they will be differ by id